# How to handle transactions in dotnet world?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, transactions

we are using linq-to-sql in a desktop project? How should we handle transactions? What about using transaction scope?

Comment: using transactions is good, what exactly are you trying to ask ?, could you be more specific? Thanks

Comment: You've asked 13 questions, and not accepted a single answer, could you work on that?

Comment: Please leave a comment when down voting, stating the reason, would be helpful for the author. Thanks

Comment: +1 @Yuriy I wanted to suggest the same :)

Answer (score 3):

Linq-to-sql supports three transaction models described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386995.aspx).

You can use [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387002.aspx) to bracket several actions.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the process of creating a business logic and data access logic layer for our application framework. We are using Linq-to-SQL. For simple transactions, we use the default L2S transaction support that the SubmitChanges() method call uses. For more complex transactions, we use Transaction Scope. Transaction scope works very well, and won't escalate to an MTC transaction if the transaction is limited to a single database and single connection.

Randy